# what on earth is -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBPAGE_VTAB

Tags: sqlite

```
sqlite> .dbinfo 
the ".dbinfo" command requires the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBPAGE_VTAB compile-time options
```

I used sqlite3 in macos terminal to open a db(*.sqlite file), but when I tried to run .dbinfo, the above error pops up. What is "-DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBPAGE_VTAB compile-time options" and how can I enable it?

Comment: That is a compile-time option used when building the SQLite library from source. It is enabled by default in builds available from the SQLite website. Where did your version come from?